# Youtube analytics API Playlists filter returns Unknown error occurred on the server

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

When retrieving my playlists statistics using the Youtube Analytics API, quite often the API returns error 500

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Unknown error occurred on the server."
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Unknown error occurred on the server."
 }
}
```

The request that I make is authorized, by turning on the `Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0` in the api explorer

Here is a [link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DMINE&start-date=2014-05-01&end-date=2014-06-30&metrics=playlistStarts%252CestimatedMinutesWatched%252Cviews%252CviewsPerPlaylistStart&filters=isCurated%253D%253D1%253Bplaylist%253D%253DPLAYLIST_ID&_h=11&) to the API explorer, which is taken from the official documentation

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I get this periodically as well and as far as I can tell it's a problem with the YouTube API, not my code.  I can go to YouTube directly and access the analytics there with no issue, it's just a problem when accessing the API.

Comment: Nope, didnt find a solution. Seems like a random error from Youtube's side